# I have a relationship between users and roles but I keep getting this error undefined index role

Tags: laravel

I have a relationship between users and roles but I keep getting this error undefined index role.

//User Model

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

//Role Model

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

//controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller
```

{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

```
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
   return view('home');

}
```

}

//view

```
<div class="info">
    <a href="#" class="d-block">{{auth()->user()->role->name}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if your relation is many to many you must change users() method to `belongsToMany()`

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't throw an `Undefined Index` error... If anything, it would be a `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.` if `auth()->user()->role` was `null`, or `Trying to get property 'role' of non-object.` if `auth()->user()` was `null` (no user logged in). Can you post the exact error and line?

Comment: Could you pls add your controller ?

Comment: this is the error message

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined index: role (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\HealthCareSystem\resources\views\includes\sidebar.blade.php)
http://localhost/HealthCareSystem/public/home

this page can only be accessed when the user is logged in

Comment: a user can only have one role

Comment: public function index()
    {
        $userid = \auth()->id();
        $user = User::find($userid);
       return view('home', compact('user'));

    }
this works but i can't use the auth inside a blade template